# MySQL: SELECT from different tables with a common ID

Tags: mysql

this is my first post after hundreds of times I've visited your site.

Simple question.

I have Two Tables, indipendent, different in all, with only one common column. 
We call it ID_Client

I don't have to modify these tables but I want to merge them and make on this a Select Query.

Table A

```
Col_ID    |Col 1    |Col 2    |Col 3    |
----------|---------|---------|---------|
40302025  |50       |  60     |  70     |
40302028  |50       |  60     |  70     |
40302030  |50       |  60     |  70     |
40302055  |50       |  60     |  70     |
40302074  |50       |  60     |  70     |
```

Table B

```
Col_ID    |Col X    |Col Y    |Col Z    |
----------|---------|---------|---------|
40302025  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |
40302028  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |
40302030  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |
40302055  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |
40302074  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |
```

Table results

```
Col_ID    |Col X    |Col Y    |Col Z    |Col 1    |Col 2    |Col 3    |
----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
40302055  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |50       |  60     |  70     |
40302074  |ABC      |  CDE    |  7ASE   |50       |  60     |  70     |
```

I have to query (like "Order", "Limit" and so on) so that the first table is dependent on the second and vice versa.

Example: I want to sort the column 2 of Table A, based on the X column of Table B where ID> 40302030

Example 2: I want to select column 3 of Table A and column B of Table X where ID> 40302030

I do not want the query to solve these examples, but I want to understand what function should I use. I tried UNION, UNION ALL, JOIN but maybe I did not understand the optics of use.

It sounds like "I want to merge two table in one and then I make the query like SELECT, ORDER BY, WHERE etc."

Thanks and sorry for my english

Carlo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should `JOIN` the two tables. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.col_ID,
  b.colx,
  b.coly,
  b.colz,
  a.col1,
  a.col2,
  a.col3
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.col_ID = b.col_ID
WHERE a.col_ID > 40302030;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a18dc/2)

The results:

```
|   COL_ID | COLX | COLY | COLZ | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 40302055 |  ABC |  CDE | 7ASE |   50 |   60 |   70 |
| 40302074 |  ABC |  CDE | 7ASE |   50 |   60 |   70 |
```

For sorting add an `ORDER BY` clause.

---

Since the two table relates to each others, then you should `JOIN` them.

You might need to use `UNION` if you want to merge the columns of the two tables in to one set of columns, and I think this isn't the case. Since you want to display all the columns from tablea and all the columns from the tableb.

Comment: Perfect!!! Great!!! But.... if I want to make a recordset on these single data I use the "COLX" or "b.COLX" ??? Ex: MyVar = rs("b.COLX")

Comment: @user2327061 - `b.colx` will be selected with the name `colx` not `b.colx` and the same for the other columns. So it should be `MyVar = rs("colx")`.

Comment: fiddle demo is broken

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
SELECT
     a.col_ID, b.colx,b.coly,b.colz,a.col1,a.col2,a.col3
FROM 
     tableA a, tableB b
WHERE 
     a.col_ID = b.colID 
ORDER BY 
    b.colx ASC
```

Hope it help.